# Zope's Virtual Host Monster and the RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, zope

My zope site was recently 'attacked' by an aggressive crawler service ran by 80legs.com which repeatedly brought it to its knees over a two day period.

I would like to block this crawler (by testing against user agent string) but this zope instance is not behind apache so there is no .htaccess file.  Zope does have its own 'Virtual Host Monster' for rewriting urls to subfolders but I can't find any reference to whether or not that can handle RewriteCond and RewriteRule statements within its 'mappings' tab.

Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve this, and if so what the syntax would be?

If this were an apache .htaccess file I would have written the following :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^80legs 
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Comment: I'm curious; is there any benefit in using VHM over web servers' rewriting?  Also, OT but, I'd like to mention that, since a year ago, after we switched  over to nginx from Apache, we've been experiencing far superior performance and smaller memory footprint.

Comment: I don't know about benefit as such...  It's just that there is no .htaccess setup on that zope instance so if it's possible to do this via the VHM then I don't have to spend hours and hours researching what's involved in setting up zope to operate with both an .htaccess and a VHM on a live site.

Comment: The VHM **only** supports communicating a specific domain name and root path to Zope, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the VHM is just to communicate from a front-end reverse proxy to Zope what domain name and initial path generated URLs must use. It does not support general rewriting. It certainly does *not* support conditions based on HTTP headers.

You'd have to write a Zope request event handler to alter URLs based on HTTP headers. This is not going to be easy unless you are prepared to write a new Python package for your server.

The easier method is to install nginx and having it handle rewriting for you, proxy for Zope and protect you against improperly behaving HTTP clients instead.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that.  Do you know of any good guides to handling the rewriting on the nginx server?  The zope instance is already on that type of server but I'm lost as to how to get a functioning .htaccess file setup.  In other platforms I've just placed the file in the route folder but this doesn't work for zope.  Thanks.

Comment: nginx does not support `.htaccess` files. Configure nginx directly. See http://developer.plone.org/hosting/nginx.html for a guide.

Comment: For what it's worth, in nginx, blocking the 80legs crawler can be done using ```if ($http_user_agent ~* 80legs) { return 301 http://www.80legs.com; }
 ```